# How to push on FormArray without FormBuilder on Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have form array, I am having hard time solving this.

this is my current code

.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.item = this.fb.group({
      codeId: ['', Validators.pattern(/^\d+$/)],
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      stepTextarea: ['', []],
      steps: [this.fb.array([]), []]
    });
}
addProcedure (e): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    const control = <FormGroup>this.item;
    const steps = <FormArray>this.item.controls['steps'];

    steps.push(control.get('stepTextarea').value);
    control.get('stepTextarea').setValue("", {onlySelf: true})
  }

onSubmit({value, valid}: {value: Item, valid: boolean}): void {
    const control = <FormGroup>this.item;
    console.log(value);
}
```

.html

```
<ol ngFor [ngForOf]="item.get('steps').controls">
  <span [formGroupName]="i">{{i}}</span>
</ol>
```

I am having hard time how to populate and also push. I cant find any tutorial.

**EDIT**

I want something like this on submit

```
{
    codeId: 123,
    name: "wew",
    stepTextarea: "",
    steps: ['asdjlkas','12312','12321']
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you want the steps to look like this on submit:

```
steps: ['asdjlkas','12312','12321']
```

you shouldn't use formGroup inside steps.

The build of the form should look like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.item = this.fb.group({
      codeId: ['', Validators.pattern(/^\d+$/)],
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      stepTextarea: [''],
      steps: this.fb.array([]) // do not enclose steps inside an array
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

This would be the way your `addProcedure` would look like:

```
addStep() {
  const control = <FormArray>this.item.get('steps');
  // push the value from stepTextArea to array
  control.push(this.fb.control(this.item.get('stepTextArea').value))
  // reset
  this.item.get('stepTextArea').reset()
}
```

And your template would look like this:

```
<div formArrayName="steps">
<h3>Steps: </h3>
<ol *ngFor="let step of item.get('steps').controls; index as i"> 
   <span>{{step.value}}</span>
</ol>
```

---

**Original answer with solution of how to do FormArray:**

`addProcedure` should look like this:

```
  addProcedure (e): void {
    const steps = <FormArray>this.item.get('steps');
    steps.push(this.fb.control())
  }
```

And your template for formarray should look something like this:

```
<div formArrayName="steps">
  <div *ngFor="let step of item.controls.steps.controls; let i = index" >
      <label>Step {{i+1}} </label>
      <input [formControlName]="i" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: anyway to view directly on my template? this is my current and it shows empty. `<ol formArrayName="steps" class="list-group" dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="steps">
                    <li *ngFor="let step of item.controls.steps.controls; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
                        {{step[i]}}
                    </li>
                  </ol>`

Comment: I believe... `{{step[i]}}` should be just `{{i}}`

Comment: it shows index on mine, not the content. and when I try `{{step}}`, it returned `[Object object]`

Comment: Well hmm... looking closer at the code, what do you expect the value should be, since you have no input field... so it wouldn't even get a value? and apparently you are using some 3rd party tool?

Comment: i have input field,  look on my `addProcedure`, it will get the `stepTextarea` value to insert on `steps` array when the `addProcedure` button is clicked.

Comment: Ah, right, now I understand. Hold on, let's see if I can't figure this one out :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143661/discussion-between-storm-spirit-and-ajt-82).

Comment: Thanks! This problem was driving me mad.