# How to push FormArray without new fields than in existing fields

Tags: javascript, angular

How to push new values at the click of a button in formArray without adding new fields. Fields already exist, which means I don't need new ones, I just need new values from those fields entered.

Look at my code:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
  <div *ngFor="let data of contactFormGroup.controls; let i = index;" formArrayName="data">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">


      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Pretraži prozivod...">
      </mat-form-field>

      <table mat-table [dataSource]="productSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Broj Proizvoda </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{ element.id }} </td>
        </ng-container>


        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Naziv proizvoda </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.name }} </td>

        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
          <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Opis proizvoda </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- quantity Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="images" class="test" >
          <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> quantity</th>
      // i need this values but on click add new object in formArray 
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="test"> <input formControlName="quantity"  type="text"> </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="images2">
          <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Add new </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <button  mat-raised-button color="primary">Add new</button>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr (click)="test(row.id)"  mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

      </table>
      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

      <div class="button-submit">
        <button (click)="openDialog2()" mat-raised-button color="warn">
          Posalji narudzbu
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Ts file:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.productSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.productSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.getProducts();
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      deliveryDate: [''],
      data: this.fb.array([this.createContact()]),
      note: [null]
    });

    this.contactList = this.form.get('data') as FormArray;
  }


  createContact(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }


  addContact() {
    this.contactList.push(this.createContact());
  }
```

This code works well when I set fields and add function addContact(). When click show new fields and work good but in this situation, I don't want new fields. I have existing fields only to enter a quantity and push id and quantity in new FormArray.
This is an example what I need: https://ibb.co/1Tj2HNc
ON click button add new. If you have any question just ask
The current code works on principle when I add the first product:
 `console.log(my form.values)`

```
data: Array(1)
0: {id: "", quantity: "99"}
```

And this is good only need id but ok... But when I add new quantity for new fields example 15 for another field and `console.log` my form values:

```
data: Array(1)
0: {id: "", quantity: "15 "}
```

override the old value and enter the new value.
It should add a new object in array with that value.

Example:

```
data: Array(2)
0: {id: "", quantity: "99"}
1: {id: "", quantity: "15"}
```

Also i need id :)

EDIT:

I forgot a piece of code:

```
  get contactFormGroup() {
    return this.form.get('data') as FormArray;
  }
```

Comment: did you try: `(this.form.get('data') as FormArray).push(<new_object>)`?

Comment: @Kumar Where did you think this was?

Comment: [ts] Cannot find name 'push'.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43841831/3519504

Comment: Maybe I will try but again i need Object with id and quantity to push.

Comment: @Kumar hhmmm different logic.. not same

Answer (score 0):

just create new function that accepts the index you want to insert the data into and the object you want to insert and it should do what you want.

```
assignContactForm(index: number, data: any): void {
  // data is object of type {id: number, quantity: number }
  this.contactFormGroup.controls[i].patchValue(data);
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand this logic.. Where I need to pass assignContactForm function?

Comment: on your form where you are getting you are getting the new id and quantity values from. you already have the index as I so use template variables to get the id and quantity and pass it to the function as one object. assign assignContactForm(i, {is, quantity}) where exactly are you getting the new values?. you haven't mentioned that.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz example ? @Mike

Comment: On submit() function 
  submit() { 
 console.log(this.form.value);
} 
After I manipulate with form value

Comment: sorry but i don't have enough time to create stackblitz example for it, but i'll be glad to make the modification for you once you have.

Comment: getContactsFormGroup(index): FormGroup {
    // this.contactList = this.form.get('contacts') as FormArray;
    const formGroup = this.contactList.controls[index] as FormGroup;
    return formGroup;
  }

Comment: I am make stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-9wuhwv?file=app/app.module.ts

Comment: On click button I need to push new object in array
In this situation only override previous

Comment: if i'm correct do you want to insert new value when ever the dodaj button is click on the index of where that button is located?

Comment: When I click "Dodaj" I want a new object. That object will have id and quantity properties. Values of id is row of table, values of quantity is entered of input text. Check stacklbitz console.

Comment: check my another same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336455/how-to-push-new-object-in-formarray-angular-6

Comment: did you understand ?

Comment: yes i see your pain, try few things but didn't get the result. i think this is similar to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150193/angular-material-editable-table-using-formarray i'll get back to you when i figure it out. if you haven't by then

Comment: have you thought about managing the form completely from the backend i know you might not get the pre-built features of reactive form but worth a try. check this out and let me know what you think https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-9wuhwv